# Filter New Products by Category

Tags: magento-1.9

i added a widget to show new products on the page

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="all_products" products_count="10" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_custom.phtml"}}
```

it works fine
however i was wondering if i could add a 'dropdown' with all the categories 
and filter the new products using that.
is there a predefined block for category that i can use or i have to create one myself??